# creating static routes for 2 subnets

Tags: networking

i need your help on this. been trying to figure out how to make this work for hours! my network skills are a bit rusty.

alright, i have 2 interface, and i want to create a static route for each.

10.10.10.0/24 gw 10.10.10.1

10.167.95.0/26 gw 10.167.95.1

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.167.95.25
    netmask 255.255.255.192
    gateway 10.167.95.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.10.10.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.10.10.1
```

how can i create this kind of route:

all 0.0.0.0 -> 10.167.95.1 interface

and for 10.0.0.0 -> 10.10.10.1 interface

---

**[EDIT]**

this is my current route -n

```
dest         gw         mask      flags     metric      ref     use    iface
0.0.0.0  10.167.95.1   0.0.0.0     UG          0         0       0     eth0
```

when i execute this

```
route add -net 10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1
```

my 10.167.95.0/26 drops, while my 10.0.0.0/24 turns okay. unless i remove the latter, 10.167.95.0/26 returns RTO.

---

**[EDIT #2]**

```
    dest         gw            mask           flags     metric      ref     use    iface
   0.0.0.0      10.167.95.1   0.0.0.0          UG        100         0       0     eth0
   10.0.0.0     0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0    U          0          0       0     eth1
   10.167.95.0  0.0.0.0       255.255.255.192  U          0          0       0     eth0


eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:a8:ec:00  
          inet addr:10.167.95.25  Bcast:10.167.95.63  Mask:255.255.255.192
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fea8:ec00/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3642 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2292 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:340931 (340.9 KB)  TX bytes:249696 (249.6 KB)
          Interrupt:18 Base address:0x2000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:a8:ec:0a  
          inet addr:10.10.10.100  Bcast:10.10.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fea8:ec0a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2215 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:466 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:151858 (151.8 KB)  TX bytes:30828 (30.8 KB)
          Interrupt:16 Base address:0x2080
```

after setting up route table above, and restart network `/etc/init.d/networking restart`
i get this

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth1.
```

---

**[EDIT #3]**

Currently my route table

```
 dest         gw            mask           flags     metric      ref     use    iface
0.0.0.0      10.167.95.1   0.0.0.0          UG        100         0       0     eth0
10.167.95.0  0.0.0.0       255.255.255.192  U          0          0       0     eth0
```

10.167.95.25 is reacheable

i want to add route for 10.10.10.0/24, so i executed this command as suggested

```
route add -net 10.10.10.0/24 dev eth1
```

routing table modified as below

```
 dest         gw            mask           flags     metric      ref     use    iface
0.0.0.0      10.167.95.1   0.0.0.0          UG        100         0       0     eth0
10.10.10.0   0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0    U          0          0       0     eth1
10.167.95.0  0.0.0.0       255.255.255.192  U          0          0       0     eth0
```

10.167.95.25 is not reacheable

10.10.10.100 is recheable

Answer (score 0):

It is moderately easy

```
 sudo route add default gw 10.167.95.1
 sudo route add -net 10.167.95.0/26 dev eth0
 sudo route add -net 10.10.10.0/24  dev eth1
```

In these three commands, the first one introduces a default gateway, the other two make explicit which interface to use to contact your two LANs.

I see no reason for commenting out the gateway in the stanza for eth0, even though I do not think it hurts either.

Comment: hi there. can you kindly look at my edit, i cant seem to make it work.

Comment: @user1735120 insert the statements network 10.0.0.0 and network 10.167.95.0 in the appropriate stanzas in /etc/network/interfaces, restart networking, try fixing the routing table again, if it does not work please post the output of ifconfig -a

Comment: hi @MariusMatutiae, kindly see edit 2, i have attached `ifconfig` and also added `network` statements in my `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: @user1735120 First error message nothing to worry about. However, I made a mistake in suggesting the route. Please check my corrected answer (the part sudo route ...) , then turn off and then on pc, insert new routes, it should work. My mistake, sorry.

Comment: hi sir, i really appreciate your patience in helping me. kindly see edit 3, i have executed your suggestion but i cant make 2 interface work. please verify my route table.

Comment: I did, your routing table now is Ok. Probably you are missing now DNS. Edit, as sudo, the file /etc/resolv.conf, and add two lines: nameserver 8.8.4.4, nameserver 8.8.8.8. Do not turn off, or restart anything, try to connect. If it works, please accept my answer

Comment: im really not sure what im doing wrong here... but i really cant make this work! :( i know the logic is correct. not sure if this helps, but im running in vsphere .

Comment: can you ping anything? try two commands: ping -I eth0 8.8.4.4, ping -I eth1 8.8.4.4

Comment: i get unknown host, i tried pinging the gateway. `ping:unknown host 10.167.95.1` & `ping:unknown host 8.8.4.4`. whenever route for 10.10.10.0/24 is defined in routing table, my 10.167.95.0 drops.

Comment: There is no host 10.167.95.1 in your LAN, that's all.